# Include collection of routes from another package in Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quick question here, I have the below code, and I want to be able to import a whole lot of routes from my package.  The routes that are imported should be controlled by the package I'm building.  If I add a new page in the package (say, ForgotPassword), then I won't want to come here and manually add an entry for ForgotPassword... It should just start working when I update to the latest version of the package.

Also, what will this route collection look like in my package project?

Any ideas welcome :D

```
...
import { RouteCollectionFromPackage } from "@my/package";
...
<Router basename="/">
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Switch>
                    { /* I WANT TO IMPORT A COLLECTION OF ROUTES FROM MY PACKAGE */}
                    <RouteCollectionFromPackage />
                    

                    { /* THESE ARE IN MY APP */}
                    <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
                    <Route exact path="/search" component={search} />
    
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
```

Thanks!!

## EDIT:

This is what I have tried, after following some of the suggestions below:

In my module:

```
const Routes = [
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />,
    <Route exact path="/ForgotPassword" component={Login} />,
    <Route exact path="/MyProfile" component={Login} />
];

export { Routes };
```

In my consuming app:

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes as PortalFrameworkRoutes, Login} from "@sal/portal";

const home = lazy(() => import("./pages/home/Home"));
const search = lazy(() => import("./pages/search/Search"));


function routes() {
    return (
        <Router basename="/">
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Switch>
                    {PortalFrameworkRoutes.map((route: Route) => route)}
                    <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
                    <Route exact path="/search" component={search} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default routes;
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
```

OR when I use `{...PortalFrameworkRoutes}` I get:

```
Spread children are not supported in React
```

## EDIT #2:

This may actually be a crucial bit of information I omitted.  In my module, the route is exported, and imported (and again exported) in an `index.tsx` like this:

```
export { Routes } from "./routes";
export { Login } from "./pages/login/Login";
```

I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, but it feels correct since I just want to do an import from the top level of my module, and have everything available there. i.e. `import { Routes as PortalFrameworkRoutes, Login } from "@sal/portal";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "@my/package" module, you should export an Array of objects where each object has a path and component property which you can then dynamically render

Then in your current file, you can use the map method to render them

```js
 
//"@my/package" module
//make sure to import the necessary components you will be adding 
   import component1 from "//..."
   import component2 from "//..."
.
   import componentN from "//..."

export myRoutes = [
   {path: "/pathToComponent1", component: component1}
   {path: "/pathToComponent2", component: component2}
           .
   {path: "/pathToComponentN", component: componentN}
]


// in your current module
import {myRoutes} from "@my/package"
<Router>
<switch>
...  
// where you need to render routes from your module
{myRoutes.map(route => <Route path={route.path} component={route.component}/>}
...
</switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I just tried this method too, but I get the following error `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`

Comment: That makes sense, I've been wondering how one could make an array of routes too. Here is what you can try.

Comment: Create an array of route Objects, each object should have a path key and a component key. you can then export this object and use it to dynamically render the routes. check out the code snippet below

Comment: This last suggestion you made almost works for me.  It doesn't render my routes specified below the `{myRoutes.map(`. Also, how would I pass exact in this case? I tried a couple of things but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Even setting exact on every single route rendered out with the map doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm I managed to get this working in an acceptable way now which I'm happy with.  Next problem is, how can I pass params through this route, and through to the Component in my package? So the component you see in the map, needs to get parameters (a settings object).

Answer (score 1):

In your package, export the routes like so:

```
const yourRoutes = [
    <Route ... />,
    <Route ... />,
];

export { yourRoutes };
```

Import it in your consuming application:

```
import { yourRoutes } from '@your/package';
```

Then use the array spread operator to include them along the other routes:

```
<Switch>
    {...yourRoutes}

    <Route path="/some/application/route" component=... />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hmm, so close.  I did all this and I ended up with the following error: `Spread children are not supported in React`.

Comment: Ah, too bad. Try expanding it manually: `{yourRoutes.map((yourRoute) => yourRoute)}`